# My code returns empty list while running Beautifulsoup for web scraping

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to scrape the reviews from yelp. When I run my code I get an empty list as my output. I used BeautifulSoup to find it. Would really appreciate it if someone can help me...

**Here is my code:**

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/bottega-louie-los-angeles')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

soup.findAll(class_='raw__09f24__T4Ezm')
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The url is dynamic, bs4 can't mimic javascript but data is also generating api calls json response as `GET` method from where easily can grab data using requests module only.

**script:**

```
import requests

URL = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/TkFEKhsCixPWlShULKvMdQ/review_feed?rl=en&q=&sort_by=relevance_desc&start=10"
jsonData=requests.get(URL).json()

for review in jsonData['reviews']:
    print(review['comment']['text'].replace('<br>','').replace('</br>',''))
```

**Output:**

```
This review is much overdue : I&#39;ve dined here quite a few times over the past few years and must admit, it was really missed when closed. My appreciation for Bottega Louie was felt more while they were shut down for over a year since the pandemic hit. Ever since they opened doors a few months ago, the energy really went up in that area.Service has always been top notch. My favorite item on their menu are their chocolate hazelnut beignets which don&#39;t resemble authentic ones at all (BL&#39;s version are way better to me). When we ordered them to-go the last time, they didn&#39;t come filled and the filling came in a container which was not the 
same. I love their fresh pastries and some of their beautiful cakes look better than they taste but their tiramisu is hands down -- the best we&#39;ve had!Their pasta dishes are ok; there 
was this seafood turmeric yellow-ish looking plate I had years ago but they took it off the menu which I&#39;ll always remember. The Caesar salad dressing is off the charts but the portion and ingredients is a rip off. I&#39;d rather go to Sweet Green for a much more satisfying Caesar salad.Pizzas have always been consistently tasty. Their packaged candy/chocolate gift section is always a great idea for friends and family visiting. Very happy to have them back in action and hope they continue to thrive.
Such a quaint and beautiful bakery/cafe. I was blown away by the beautiful scenery. The food was amazing as well. I orderedMushroom fries- hmmm interesting flavor. Not great though. 3/5Soufflé pancake- Heaven on earth!! 10/10Breakfast sandwich(?) It was very delicious. A little messy, but the bacon was AMAZING???-7/10THE Basic Breakfast which was basic- still fresh ND well 
prepared. 6/10The pizza with broccoli. This was a no for me. For 28.00...nope. 2/10. However, 
the ingredients were fresh. If it were something other than broccoli. It would have been very 
good.All in all, a great spot. Cons- The dogs on the patio are a bad addition. There should be a dogs only area. I have terrible allergies, and we sat next to 2 huge dogs!!! Very bizarre to bring your dog to brunch.
When youve been here before you get used to certain dishes. The lobster hash is now different. **insert sad face** They don&#39;t make it with crispy home style potatoes now they use hash 
browns which come in a little circle; and comes in a sauce: it is nowhere near the amount that they used to serve. See previous pictures  I also ordered the beignets and they came out burnt amount burnt so I sent them back.
No reservation? If you&#39;re a party of ~3 or less, just take a seat at the bar for weekend brunch. It&#39;s still a lovely experience without the hour-long wait time at the seated portion of the restaurant.I ordered...- Smoked Salmon Benedict: 5/5. The bombbb. Your typical poached egg and hollandaise sauce, but on top of a crispy hash brown (and served with a side salad). It was SO good, and this is coming from someone who doesn&#39;t like runny eggs. The serving 
size is generous and I was full after the first egg. The salad is simple, but fresh and delicious.- Mimosa: 3/5. Standard drink, nothing special. All cocktails for brunch are $18, so I&#39;d recommend going for something like the Juicy instead. The mint and cucumber in the Juicy make for a lighter, more refreshing drink (and boozier from the vodka).Service was great, and everyone was very friendly considering how busy it was. If you&#39;re serious about getting a sit-down meal at BL, I&#39;d highly recommend getting a reservation in advance. Enjoy!
One of the best brunch spots for the money. This place is not overly priced and you&#39;ll come out feeing you had one of the best meals of your life.When my girlfriend and I went, we were seated fairly quickly and treated really well from the get go. I recommend coming a bit earlier during the weekend brunch as the line can build up fast. As for the food. Everything we ordered was amazing. The best part of the meal had to be the lobster hash. A close second would be the calamari. Every bite we had on the table was delicious and you probably can&#39;t go wrong with anything you order here. The desserts here are also fantastic! Everything is freshly made and wonderfully tasting! Definitely need to come check this place out if you are around. It is worth the wait and worth the money. Come check this place out!
Being half Italian I feel I can spot a great Italian meal right when I taste it so after stopping in for Valentines dinner tonight I can say that this is delicious food and nothing like so many of the non authentic Italian restaurant chains all around the US. They have a great selection of desserts and many will be stopping in for those, but the restaurant service is the real best part. They don&#39;t take reservations, nor can you put your name on a waitlist digitally like they say they can do on their VM, but still we only waited 25 minutes tonight and it 
was worth it.I had to get an Italian Soda to drink with my meal because they have been something that I have loved since childhood but rarely see anymore, so if you&#39;re in the mood for 
something sweet I would highly recommend ordering one.  For the food we ordered the Carpaccio 
to start and it was very good and for $18 it was a fair price.  For our entrees we got the Carbonara (which was my favorite) and the Burrata pizza.  I can say the pizza is the best that I&#39;ve had in DTLA, Pizzanista is my other favorite, I was pleasantly surprised how good it was. It had crisped garlic on top and they went above by cooking the spinach before adding it to the pizza which is the authentic way and sadly many other places don&#39;t focus on the smaller details as well. Overall a casual and delicious meal. It&#39;s priced fairly and can get very busy depending on the day and time so I would be prepared to wait around a half an hour to 
be seated. I will be back again soon.
The. Best. Desserts!! Came here with a friend for a celebratory dinner. The food was pretty good. I got the salmon. It was a little bit unevenly seasoned but nothing too bad. My friend mentioned that the pasta was a little bit heavy on the butter. That being said, still great experience overall. Now the desserts, that&#39;s where they killed it! We got a box of macarons with assorted flavors. I personally loved the espresso and strawberry ones but each flavor was strong and well executed. We also tried three of their pastries (not exactly sure what their names are) the lemon tart and chocolate bar was amazing. Rich in flavor and well balanced. The apple tart was a little heavy with the apple to filling ratio but still amazing! I highly recommend dropping by to try some of the desserts! The service was amazing as well and there was convenient psrking across the street in a garage. (You do have to pay though) Overall, I would give dinner a 4/5, dessert a 5/5, service a 5/5, and environment a 5/5.
Beautiful interior with amazing food.There was a bit of a wait but that&#39;s okay!The pizza was thinly crustedMeatballs were juicyCoffee was strongPasta was flavorfulWhat more can you ask for?
Review for their desserts (no food): Went here on a Sunday night for some sweets. There&#39;s 
separate seating for ppl getting food vs desserts. Obvi the seating for the restaurant is fancier. Maybe we came too late but most of the cakes were sold out by the time we got there. We were still able to get a small tiramisu for around $18 (if my memory is correct). The full size cake is $40.  I was shocked at how expensive the small cake was but it tasted so smooth and creamy. In other words it was very good so I guess I understand why it&#39;s expensive. But would I buy it again? Probs not. It&#39;s a once in a lifetime experience. Our group also got macarons and that was pricey too. But their macarons are good quality and taste good too. Again, 
I prob won&#39;t spend this much money on desserts ever again. But I do recommend this place when you want to treat yourself to fancy desserts.
First time at this spot, man is it popular BECAUSE it was packed! Picked up some goodies for my moms birthday.  I got:LE NOIRChocolate sponge cake, milk chocolate ganache &amp; dark chocolate ganacheRASPBERRY CHOCOLATEChocolate joconde, raspberry marmalade &amp; chocolate caramel ganacheThey pastries were beautiful! Each looked like a piece of art too pretty to eat! I HAD A BITE OF THE LE NOIR. You talking mouth watering good! The flavors were rich, paired with vanilla Ice cream.. DELICIOUS. Definitely recommend
```